# Note taking app for to use with pen tablets

Tags: software-recommendation, wacom, graphics-tablet, vector-drawings

I am looking for an app that with which I can draw on it to make sketches and take notes with my Wacom tablet. It should preferably support "new page" so that after my work I can save the whole notebook as a PDF so that I don't have to save them one by one.

Answer (score 4):

I have another recommendation you might want to look into: [Write](http://www.styluslabs.com/) by Stylus Labs. Disclaimer: I have yet to vet it (I just downloaded it and am about to use it for the first time...I will update my answer after trying it out).

It has one major advantage over Xournal, which is that it has infinite scroll. Looks like it has a lot of nice features, like being able to make bookmarks, and insert new text wherever you want in the page.

To install dependencies: `sudo apt-get install libqt5widgets5 libqt5network5 libqt5svg5`

Comment: do you have any updates?

Comment: @YauhenYakimenka Sadly, no updates. The internal SSD on my dual-boot laptop bit the dust, and it was high time for an upgrade. When I got a new PC, I decided not to do a dual-boot drive for simplicity's sake, since everything I needed for school/work could be done on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You could try xournal, I seem to recall it has support for "export to pdf": http://xournal.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Xournal++ in my experience has better palm detection and works with the buttons on my yoga 14

Answer (score 0):

Try Jarnal, a cross platform portable application (java) for handwritten notetaking, pdf annotation.
http://www.dklevine.com/general/software/tc1000/jarnal.htm